# Is it possible to get user detailed using facebook API V2.6

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the "taggable_friends" api to get the list of all friends then uses the user ID (a string of 110 chars) to get user detailes like this:

```
      FB.api('/' + gFriend.id , 'GET',{},
      function(response) {
        console.log("response",response)
      });
```

In the result I get an error

```
(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {The user Id I have submitted}
```

Did FB blocked user details API in version 2?

Comment: taggable_friends is for tagging only, why would you need the details of the friends for that?

Comment: I want to show friend pic collage

Comment: why would you need that for tagging? and why would you need the user details of friends for that?

Comment: They did a major change in V2 friends are now only app fiend so because  have a new app I get 0 friends, the only thing that worked is tagged friends

Comment: i know, but you are not allowed to use taggable_friends for anything else than tagging. that´s just how it is. if you just want to create a photo collage, you have to live with app users only.

Answer (score 1):

`taggable_friends` if for tagging only, you can´t use it for anything else and you don´t get a User ID. You only get a "tagging token" that can only be used for tagging. If you just want to create a "friend pic collage", you need to use `/me/friends` instead. Of course you will only get friends who authorized your app with the `user_friends` permission.

Answer (score 1):

> [from comments] I want to show friend pic collage

The `taggable_friends` endpoint does return URLs of the friend’s profile pictures already.

You get a data structure like this,

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "AaKYNqeDaP…",
      "name": "Foo Barski",
      "picture": {
        "data": {
          "is_silhouette": false,
          "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/…"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "AaKBGEbAAvYU…",
      "name": "Some One Else",
      "picture": {
        "data": {
          "is_silhouette": false,
          "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/…"
        }
      }
    },
```

So all you need to do is use those URLs provided in the picture structure.